# How to use Scala implicit class in Java

Tags: java, scala, cloudera-cdh

I have a Scala Implicit class from RecordService API, which i wanted to use in Java file.

```
package object spark {

   implicit class RecordServiceContext(ctx: SparkContext) {
     def recordServiceTextFile(path: String) : RDD[String] = {
      new RecordServiceRDD(ctx).setPath(path)
          .map(v => v(0).asInstanceOf[Text].toString)
    }
  }

}
```

Now i am trying to import this in a Java file using below import.

```
import com.cloudera.recordservice.spark.*;
```

But i am not able to use recordServiceTextFile("path") from sparkContext.

In Scala the import is little different and its working.

Comment: I don't see an implicit class.

Comment: Importing Scala code in Java code is not a trivial operation to my eyes. It requires some understanding of the javac internals. Also the question is not clear. Can you be a but more clear on the question ? The more "full" the question the better the answer.

Comment: @Ramesh You're welcome but that wasn't me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is simple definition of implicit class in package object

```
package object spark {
  implicit class Ext(param: Int) {
    def a = param + 1
  }
}
```

and here is how you can use it from java

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        spark.package$.MODULE$.Ext(123).a();
    }
}
```

so you can basically use `RecordServiceContext` as a method that wraps your `SparkContext` and adds an extra method that you can call. That is optimization for implicit classes.

That would be something like this:

```
SparkContext c = ???
RDD<String> rdd = com.cloudera.recordservice.spark.package$.MODULE$.RecordServiceContext(c)
   .recordServiceTextFile("asdf");
```

Answer (score 1):

A `package object spark` is compiled to a class `package` in the package `spark`. The implicit class `RecordServiceContext` will get compiled to a static method `RecordServiceContext` (that's scala's implicit def) in `package` and a class `package$RecordServiceContext`.

So the following code should do it:

```
import com.cloudera.recordservice.spark.*;

//some code

RDD<String> rdd = package.RecordServiceContext(myContext).recordServiceTextFile(pathToFile);

//some code
```

But `package` is probably a reserved keyword, and Java has no way of escaping them as far as I know. So you'll have to do some reflection to invoke the `RecordServiceContext` method.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SparkContext ctx = ...
 RecordServiceContext rsct = new RecordServiceContext(ctx)
 recordServiceTextFile("/your_path")
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it.

```
String s = new spark.RecordServiceContext("safa").recordServiceTextFile("dsf");
```

I changed the signatures though.

My Scala class looks like this ,

```
object spark {
implicit class RecordServiceContext(ctx: String) {
 def recordServiceTextFile(path: String) : String = {
 "test"
}
}
}
```

My java class looks like this,

```
 public class TestScalaCall {
public static void main(String args[]){
    String s = new spark.RecordServiceContext("safa").recordServiceTextFile("dsf");
}
}
```

Edit ---

So a quick look of the Scala change requests shows us [this](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-4344).

They are actually working on making a class defined under a `package object` behave the same way as defining it inside a regular `package`. But that is targeted for the yet to be release `2.12` .

So the recommendation they are giving is keep only absolutely necessary classes/objects that do not needs any external interaction inside package objects. Otherwise keep them under regular packages.
So for now you need to not use the `package object` construct.

Also , a point worth pondering "Does it really make sense to define something that is accessible on the outside inside a package object ? "

Comment: your implicit class missing `package` before `object spark`, that's the main problem i am facing...

Comment: i added the explanation in the answer. That is something that the scala team is working on.